# Delay between TCP ACK and next packet

Tags: tcp, ip, tcpclient

I have a simple HTML form with file upload

```
<form action="...." enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" name="d">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

I noticed strange delay in uploading and debugged with wireshark. There is a strange 2 second delay between ACK for first packet and second one been sent. 
Any idea why this is happening?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a delay introduced by the application & not by the TCP stack. You can see that the application pushed data of length 577 initially, probably a http header & received a ACK for it after nearly 200ms which equals the TCP delayed ACKs timeout & its absolutely fine. After that the 2 sec is the delay taken by the application to read the file from the system. Once the file is read, you can see that it sends bigger blocks of data filling the entire TCP segment length i.e 1514. 
You need to check the file system or the way the application reads the file which actually causes the delay.